# How to expose a home PC behind CG-NAT using a VPS?

Tags: ssh, vpn, port-forwarding, dmz

Previously I had my home workstation PC directly exposed to the internet simply by setting it as the DMZ PC in my router's settings, and I could access any services I was running on it: SSH, Web Server, Remote Desktop, etc. I had DynDNS configured and I also own a domain, with a subdomain DNS entry pointing to my router's external IP, so I could remotely access it, any port, from anywhere on the world using a fixed name, be it either `home.mydomain.com` or `myuser.dyndns.com`. Life was good.

Now I moved and my new ISP sets me behind a CGNAT, ie, my router's "external" address is in the 100.64.0.0/10 range, so it cannot be reached from the outside anymore (and DynDNS is also dead, but that's irrelevant). ISP does not provide IPv6, unfortunately, and switching ISPs is not an option in my area.

That said, my company recently subscribed a VPS plan for my team, running Ubuntu 18.04, and I have full control over it. I can SSH to it, install any software, configure it to my liking. Currently it only runs SSH on a non-standard port and a small API service on a custom port, all other ports (including 80) are available. I've already set `home.mydomain.com` as a `CNAME` DNS entry pointing to it.

So, what's the best strategy to use this new asset to finally have my home workstation PC exposed to the internet as it was before?

While googling for CGNAT circumvention I've read a lot about SSH Reverse Tunnels/Proxying, SOCKS, VPN Servers, but I'm still not sure what is the best tool and setup to achieve the goal in this scenario.

My requirements:

- **Open source, free software only**:  sure, I have total control over the VPS, but I'd like to keep the extra software fingerprint to a minimum. I'm fine `apt install`'ing anything from official repositories, and maybe a github repo. On my workstation, also running Ubuntu, I can install more obscure stuff.
- **Self-hosted solutions**: Anything that usually requires an external service (paid or not), such as Serveo, LocalTunnel, OpenVPN, etc, I'd like to install its server version on the VPS. I don't want my traffic routed to yet another company I must trust.
- **No client install (preferably)**: I'd like to access my workstation from anywhere, be it my laptop, a friend's PC, college, work, using regular browsers, SSH clients, Remote Desktop (RDP or VNC) clients, etc, software that are usually already installed or generally available.
- **No punching individual port holes (preferably)**: It should be as if my workstation *is* `home.mydomain.com`, directly exposed to the internet. It's fine if I have to "remap" ports, using a rule such as remote port = local port + 10000 (so web server would be accessible at port 10080), but otherwise I'd like it to be as close to a DMZ as possible.

The closest I got is `ssh [-R xx:localhost:yy]... home.mydomain.com` on the workstation, using a series of predefined ports, and setting `GatewayPorts yes` on the VPS `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. It's good, but I feel there might be a better solution. It would be *awesome* if the solution was based on the domain used to access the VPS. For example, only forward (all) requests if accessed via `home.mydomain.com`, and act normally if reached via `vps.mycompany.com`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, SSH tunnels are not suitable for this purpose. Of course, it works, but you have to run as many tunnels as ports you want to forward.

VPN is probably the best option to achieve that.
You configure the VPN server on the VPS, you connect your home server(s) as VPN client(s), and when you are not home, you connect your laptop or remote computer to this VPN, as a client, and you will be able to reach your home server(s) as if you were in the same local network, you do not even have to assign them a "public IP".

If you want to assign a public IP to one of your home server(s), you will have to configure a second public IP on the VPS (so it stays available from its primary IP), and then, setup 1:1 NAT with the VPS's firewall (iptables). And this home server will be configured to use the VPN as a gateway, so outgoing packets go through the VPS's secondary IP instead of your home ISP's IP.

If you have many home servers, you can do 1:1 NAT if you can get more than 2 IPs assigned to the VPS. Else, you will have to use port forwarding if you want a single IP to be used with different home servers.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Any directions on what VPN Servers and Clients to install and how to configure them to this scenario? Which software do I have to install on each machine? How exactly would I access my workstation from, say, a friend's PC?

Comment: OpenVPN works good, IPsec seems to be a good choice too but I have no experience with this.

There is "one click" installers for OpenVPN like this one:
https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install

But I recommend to read about OpenVPN and its configuration to understand what this script does, and how to tweak the settings.

And you will use iptables for 1:1 NAT or port forwarding.

If your friend's PC is not connected to the VPN, it can only access the home server if you configured 1:1 NAT or port-forwarders between your VPS public IP and the home server's IP it got from the VPN.

Comment: @MestreLion: "NAT" is the key word here. Once you have a VPN link, you can set up port forwarding from the VPN server's public IP address, through the tunnel, to your local hosts – then connect to the VPN server's public IP address. With the tunnel, everything's almost the same as if you were dealing with a normal home router.

Comment: @u1686_grawity so basically this would be similar to a home router's DMZ setting, correct? In this analogy, the VPS's public 2nd IP would be the "WAN" IP to my home LAN, and the DMZ'd IP would be my home server's internal VPN IP, is that so? And `iptables` is the tool to set up this "1:1 NAT / DMZ" on the VPS, cool!

Comment: @MestreLion: When doing NAT – yes, it's exactly like DMZ. Both DMZ and port-forwarding work the same way and are set up through iptables `-j DNAT`; the only difference is that port-fowarding rules are usually set for specific ports, while DMZ is for everything else. (In fact, even your home router probably just uses iptables under the hood to implement them...)

Comment: @MestreLion: One thing to keep in mind is that IP communications must go both ways, so it's not technically enough for packets to reach your home PC via the link – the home PC also needs to know that it should respond via the same link as well; it's not always automatic. Depending on VPN config (and on the OS running on your home PC), the latter might just work; or it might need 'policy routing' (Linux specific); or it might need additional `SNAT` rules (same kind of problem as 'NAT hairpin'). If in doubt, tcpdump to see where packets go or don't go.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Thank you so much for such valuable insights and hints! Unfortunately DigitalOcean (which hosts my VPS as a droplet) seems to have no option to purchase an additional IPv4 (I might just create a dedicated droplet for the VPN). As for the clients, initially I'll use Ubuntu, but eventually some WIndows clients will be needed, so I hope it does the right thing when routing reply packets coming from the VPN subnet

Comment: @MestreLion: It seems that they do https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/reserved-ips/ – although the traffic is NATed by DO to the corresponding internal 'anchor IP' before it reaches your server, but that doesn't prevent you from NATing it further.

Answer (score 2):

This probably won't help you, but I think it's good to highlight PCP (Port Control Protocol) as fitting this use case.  Your ISP would have to support this (I don't know how prevalent ISP support of PCP is, being a pessimist, I'd guess not very...)

PCP is basically one of the latest in the family of UPnP, NAT-PMP type protocols.  PCP has MAP and PEER functions that let your client request a port-forward at the ISP level (at their CGNAT).  If anyone knows of an ISP doing this (or better yet has actually used it in the real world) I'd love to hear about it.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6887

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_Control_Protocol

[Using PCP (Port Control Protocol) in practice?](https://superuser.com/questions/1301857/using-pcp-port-control-protocol-in-practice)

Comment: I doubt my ISP supports it, but it's really worth investigating. Seems like a winner for my use case. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Request a static IPv6 prefix from your ISP. Get IPv6 for all your Internet access.

Configure IPv6 tunnelbroker, VPN, or other transition methods for when you only have legacy IPv4 access.

Comment: IPv6 is not available from my ISP, unfortunately. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Then request your ISP add IPv6 service, or get a better ISP. Removing the ISP's NAT meets all your requirements.

Comment: I've requested already, but they don't provide it, nor they are willing to remove the CGNAT without a (hugely expensive) business plan for static IP. I have no power over the ISP and there's no other suitable ISP in my area. Is there any solution I could put the VPS to good use?

Comment: And, if IPv6 tunnelbroker / VPN are viable solutions for my scenario of legacy IPV4, care to explain them in more detail? Also, can the IPv6 tunnelbroker be self-hosted on the VPS?

Answer (score 1):

Bumped into this problem and although late to the party thought this would help someone.

A simple way to accomplish this is reverse tunneling as follows:

On Client(Machine with no public ip):
ssh -R 7680:localhost:7677 root@remotemachine (Do not exit this prompt)

7680 WILL OPEN ON REMOTE MACHINE
7677 IS ALREADY OPEN ON LOCAL/CLIENT MACHINE

On Remote Machine: ssh localhost -p 7680

and you will connect to client.

The problem is the connection will die when you exit the ssh session on Client.

So use autossh which can background:

autossh -M 20000 -f -N -R 7680:localhost:7677 -C root@remotemachine

Now you can exit the shell and the connection will not drop

Comment: I've already mentioned this solution in my question, and _"it's good but not great"_, but thanks for detailing the additional commands for it, including `autossh`.